# Highlight cells with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried several option how to highlight excel cells using Openpyxl 3.0.6 in python 3.8.2 but no ones from the code below work for me its look like everting is ok is run, but did not highlight cells.

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.styles.fills import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors

excel_path = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Sample.xlsx')
currentSheet1 = excel_path['Template']
currentSheet3 = excel_path['Template Update']

#color the rows in sheet
redFill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=colors.Color(rgb='00FF0000'))

currentSheet1.cell(row=20, column=11).fill= PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='F2DCDB', 
end_color='F2DCDB')

currentSheet1.cell(row=20, column=11).fill= PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='F2DCDB', 
end_color='F2DCDB')

ft = Font(color="FF0000")
a=currentSheet1.cell(row=20, column=10)
a.fill = PatternFill(fill_type = 'solid',bgColor='00ff00' )

fill_cell = currentSheet1.cell(row=20, column=10)
red_color = colors.Color(rgb='00FF0000')
solid_red_fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=red_color)
fill_cell.fill = solid_red_fill
currentSheet3.cell(row=1, column=1).fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE", fill_type = "solid")
currentSheet1.cell(row=20, column=10).fill = PatternFill(fill_type="solid", bgColor=colors.BLUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not save the workbook. Maybe you didn't post the entire code,
but if you did, then you need to add the **save()** call at the end, to write the
changes to the disk file.

As for the formatting, here's a simple example that works well, it sets the
**background color** of cell D5 (row=5,col=4) to red, and the **font** in cell
C2 (row=2, col=3) to red:

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl.styles.fills import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors

excel_path = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Sample.xlsx')
currentSheet1 = excel_path['Template']
currentSheet3 = excel_path['Template Update']

#color the rows in sheet
redFill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=colors.Color(rgb='00FF0000'))
currentSheet1.cell(row=5, column=4).fill = redFill

ft = Font(color="FF0000")
currentSheet1.cell(row=2, column=3).font = ft

excel_path.save(filename='C:/Users/Sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: thank you, it is working! for example if I have a loop and want to highlight specific cells in different color then I can save it on the end of the loop or it should be always when loop  highlight cells?

Comment: No problem. Since you're new to StackOverflow (SO), please have a look at [this
page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to learn the SO way of
doing things. In particular, SO discourages the use of comments for discussion,
that's one of the reasons the signal-to-noise ratio here is so good.

Comment: You can save your workbook once, at the end.